# Preposition to use for challenge (in or of)

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm struggling with the choice of preposition to use for the following sentence.

> 1. Amy enjoys the challenge **of** doing *X,Y,Z* to improve her run time.
> 2. Amy enjoys the challenge **in** doing *X,Y,Z*  to improve her run time.

Are they both acceptable?

Answer (score -1):

Though using "in" is possible,

in this context 
the use of preposition "of" is only acceptable.

Besides it's preferable according to [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20challenge%20of%2C%20the%20challenge%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20challenge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20challenge%20in%3B%2Cc0).